# jquery flowplayer tooltip: overriding the default event parameter

Tags: jquery, tooltip, flowplayer

By default [flowplayer tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) opens on mouseenter,mouseleave events. I want to override it, so that tooltip is shown onclick

I tried using code:

`$("#datepicker").tooltip({
    events: {
        def: "click,mouseleave"
    }});`

But it didn't worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean it didn' work?

I made this fiddle an it works: http://jsfiddle.net/TEyJZ/ (look at the small a above the images when you click)

are you sure you are not using the wrong selector? (datepicker makes it sound much more like a datepicker plugin)